# Related to restart program and simplify if else statement

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String Day; // The user’s name.
    TextIO.put("This program is to tell you what to eat for today.");
    TextIO.put("\nBefore it starts, can you tell me what's the day today?");
    int count;
    int CCount;
    String Answer;
    CCount = 0;
    count = 0;
    do {
        Day = TextIO.getln();

        if (Day.equals("Monday")) {
            System.out.print("Eat Chocolates");
            break;
        } else if (Day.equals("Mon")) {
            System.out.print("Eat Chocolates");
            break;
        } else if (Day.equals("MON")) {
            System.out.print("Eat Chocolates");
            break;
        } else if (Day.equals("mon")) {
            System.out.print("Eat Chocolates");
            break;
        } else if (Day.equals("monday")) {
            System.out.print("Eat Chocolates");
            break;
        } else if (Day.equals("MONDAY")) {
            System.out.print("Eat Chocolates");
            break;
        } else if (Day.equals(false)); // No necessary , can be delete
        count = count + 1;
        System.out.print("Fail to proceed #" + count);
        if (count == 3) {
            System.out.print("\nProgram Terminate");
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            System.out.print("\nPlease re-eneter the answer : ");
        }
    } while (true);

    System.out.print("\nNow's can you tell me what's your horoscope?");
    String Horoscope;
    String Name;
    String CrazyThing;
    double Salary;
    double Annually;

    do {
        Horoscope = TextIO.getln();
        if (Horoscope.equals("Libra")) {
            System.out.print("Seriously?");
            System.out.print("\nYou are?");
            Name = TextIO.getln();
            System.out.print("Hi! " + Name + " How are you~");
            break;
        } else if (Horoscope.equals("Gemini")) {
            System.out.print("Oh,okay~ Nice to meet you.");
            break;
        } else if (Horoscope.equals("Aries")) {
            System.out.print("Wow, you're rich~");
            System.out.print("\nNow, tell me how much you've earned per month?");
            Salary = TextIO.getlnDouble();
            System.out.print("Hmmmmm $ " + Salary + " , right?");
            Annually = Salary * 12;
            System.out.print("\nYour annually salary are ");
            System.out.printf("$ " + "%.2f", Annually);
            break;
        } else if (Horoscope.equals("Leo")) {
            System.out.print("You're full of courages~");
            System.out.print("Now, tell me ~ What's the most crazy thing you ever do before?");
            CrazyThing = TextIO.getln();
            System.out.print(CrazyThing + "?");
            break;
        } else if (Horoscope.equals(true)); //Not necessary, can be delete
        CCount = CCount + 1;
        System.out.print("Fail to proceed #" + CCount);
        if (CCount == 3) {
            System.out.print("\nProgram Terminate");
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            System.out.print("\nPlease re-eneter your horoscope again : ");
        }
    } while (true);

    System.out.println("Do you wish to restart the program again?");
    Answer = TextIO.getln();
    if (Answer.equals("Yes"));

}
```

I would like to ask two question in this post (Sorry if my question may look very stupid, but I really need some help).

Question 1: How can I restart my program again? At the end of the horoscope, I would like to ask whether the user want to restart all over again or not.

Question 2: Is there any method that can simplify the code through alphabet?
For example in my code , I have set MON and mon and Mon, is there any method that can combine this three into one?

Comment: `Day.toLower().equals("mon")`

Comment: Have an outter loop which wraps up the variable intiialisation.  You're current (inner) loop will need some kind of exit condition

Comment: Question 2 - Put the possible matches in some kind of `List` and use `contains` or possibly some kind of regular expression or maybe even `String#toLowerCase#startsWith`

Comment: Restart program, enclose your code with another do block which would test a boolean variable set by user input inside said do block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have time currently to answer question one, but question two is

```
    if(day.toLowerCase().equals("mon")){ /*this makes the user input all lowercase,
                                        so you dont have to detect case anomalies*/ 
    }
```

As suggested by UnknownOctopus you could also use

```
if(day.equalsIgnoreCase("mon"))
```

And you would get the same effect.

**EDIT:**
For question one you need to make a boolean called `wantsToPlay` or something like that, and set it to true (`boolean wantsToPlate = true;`.
Then you put the rest of your program into a while loop that says

```
while(wantsToPlay){
//program
//ask user if they want to play again
//if input is yes or yay or whatever then{
//wantsToPlay = true;
//}else{
//wantsToPlay = false;
}
```

Comment: Why not `.equalsIgnoreCase("mon")` ?

Comment: That also works. There are many different methods. I can add that to my answer.